# "inc ecx" Instruction operands must be the same size?

Tags: assembly, masm32

I am trying to write a little program in MASM. On one line, when I try increasing ECX, I get this error... It doesn't seem to make any sense, since there is only one operand!

Here is the relevant code:

```
mov ecx, eax
lea eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]
lea ecx, BYTE PTR [eax+4]
inc ecx
```

In the beginning, EAX is just the length of a string, in this 0x05.

So, does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Why is your second line LEA rather than a simple MOV?

Comment: Well, I'm doing a crackme and simply copied the instruction from its algorithm. I have just begun learning assembly and am not quite sure the difference between MOV and LEA yet.

Comment: Think of `MOV` as being the C equivalent of `x = y`, and `LEA` being `x = &y` (notice it it gets the *address* of `y`, not the *value* of `y`)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually replace the last two lines (that you gave) with:

```
lea ecx, BYTE PTR [eax+5]
```

`LEA` gets the address of an operand, so for `BYTE PTR [eax+4]` that would just be the value `eax+4`, which gets stored in `ecx`. Since you're incrementing afterwards, you can just combine the two additions into one, so you can use `BYTE PTR [eax+5]` instead.

Comment: OK, apparently my masm32 is bugged. I deleted that line, and now its giving me the same error - on an empty line!

Comment: There may be a stray Unicode character somewhere. Try retyping those few lines and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

`BYTE PTR` makes little sense in this context, and can safely be removed (it doesn't cause any errors for me though). `LEA` computes effective addresses, which can also be used to perform some general arithmetic.

What the code snippet does is this:

```
ecx = eax
eax = ecx
ecx = eax + 4
ecx++
```

Which could have been replaced by a single instruction:

```
lea ecx,[eax+5]
```